# Rails optional parameters - refactor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, optional-parameters

So I have this module with all most all the methods having the same optional parameter. How can I refactor that?

```
class A
  module B

   def ab(name,type = :default)
     ##do stuff
   end

   def abc(name,type = :default)
     ##do stuff
   end

   def abcd(name,type = :default)
     ##do stuff
   end
  end
end
```

So is there some kind of way to refactor *type* optional parameter on methods

Comment: Well, it depends on the methods and their purposes. If it makes sense and they share some functionality, you can combine them into one function and pass a third parameter that tells the function to implement ab, abc, or abcd.

But if the methods have very different functionality, leaving them separate is better, even though you will be repeating the optional parameter 3 times.

Comment: @AbM all the methods has different functionality and doesn't share any.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
  @@type = :default

  def ab(name, type = @@type)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: we still keep on assigning values to type in every method right?

Comment: Right - this is an abbreviated example.